Finding an integrating factor of an ODE
EDIT - I've changed $\dot x$ and $\dot y$ because, unfortunately, my lecturers made mistakes.
I'm trying to find an integrating factor for the following ODE:
$ \left\{ 
\begin{array}
\dot \dot x =\frac{y+1}{x}\\ 
\dot y = \frac{y}{x^2}-1
\end{array}
\right. $
I'm asked to find it in the form of $M(\frac{y}{x})$,  and I get stuck finding it:
I know that $ \frac{\partial M}{\partial x} = \frac{-y}{x^2} M'(z) $, $ \frac{\partial M}{\partial y} = \frac{M'(z)}{x} $
And we search for $M$ such that:
$$ \frac{\partial (M \dot x)}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial (M \dot y)}{\partial y} = 0 $$
I've found that $$ M(y/x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+\frac{y^2}{x^2})}}$$
However, I couldn't find the hamiltonian:
since we now get that our system is
$ \left\{ 
\begin{array}
\dot \dot x =M(\frac{y}{x}) \frac{y+1}{x}\\ 
\dot y = M(\frac{y}{x})(\frac{y}{x^2}-1)
\end{array}
\right. $
I get that $$ \frac{\partial H}{\partial y} = \dot x $$
And from there, I see that $$ H = \ln(\sqrt{\frac{y^2}{x^2} + 1} + \frac{y}{x}) +\sqrt{y^2 + x^2} + f(x) $$
But now, when making sure $$ \frac{\partial H}{\partial x} = - \dot y $$, I can't find $f(x)$ in terms of only $x$. Did I make a mistake somewhere?

It's from my homework, I've been stuck on it for couple of hours. Apparently, now I've received an email that there was a mistake - we should have $ \dot y = \frac{y}{x^2} - 1 $.
Oh well. Pretty annoying.

Which of the two versions do you want to solve?

I apologize, I've edited the post.

You probably made a mistake in the calculation of $\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}$. Let $H=H_1+H_2+f(x)$, where
\begin{align}
H_1&=\ln\left(\sqrt{\frac{y^2}{x^2}+1}+\frac{y}{x}\right)
=\ln\left(\sqrt{y^2+x^2}+y\right)-\ln(x), \tag{1} \\
H_2&=\sqrt{y^2+x^2}. \tag{2}
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial H_1}{\partial x}&=\frac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{y^2+x^2}}}{\sqrt{y^2+x^2}+y}-\frac{1}{x}=\frac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{y^2+x^2}}\left(\sqrt{y^2+x^2}-y\right)}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x}
=-\frac{y}{x\sqrt{y^2+x^2}}, \tag{3} \\
\frac{\partial H_2}{\partial x}&=\frac{x}{\sqrt{y^2+x^2}}, \tag{4}
\end{align}
hence
$$
\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}=\frac{-\frac{y}{x}+x}{\sqrt{y^2+x^2}}+f'(x). \tag{5}
$$
On the other hand,
$$
\dot{y}=M\!\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\left(\frac{y}{x^2}-1\right)
=\frac{\frac{y}{x^2}-1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}}}
=\frac{\frac{y}{x}-x}{\sqrt{y^2+x^2}}. \tag{6}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}=-\dot{y} \implies f'(x)=0 
\implies f(x)=\text{constant}. \tag{7}
$$

Ah, that's unfortunate. Thank you!
